# Numpy memmap cannot restore numpy array from .npy

Tags: numpy

## Question

Please help find a way to restore numpy array from .npy file using Numpy memmap.

#### MNIST data

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

# Split data into training and test
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
print(X_train[9179][599])
-----> 200.0
```

#### Save to .npy

```
import numpy as np
np.save("X_train.npy", X_train)
```

#### Restore from npy into memmap

```
X_mm = np.memmap('X_train.npy', dtype=type(X_train[0][0]), mode="r", shape=(X_train.shape))
print(X_mm[9179][599])
-----> 0.0  (data is not restored)

from numpy.lib.format import open_memmap
X_mm = open_memmap('X_train.npy', mode='r', dtype=type(X_train[0][0]), shape=(X_train.shape))
X_mm[9179][599]
-----> 0.0  (data is not restored)
```

## numpy load

If used numpy load, the data can be restored. Hence it is about memmap.

```
X_mm = np.load('X_train.npy')
X_mm[9179][599]
-----> 200.0
```

Comment: `np.load` has its own version of memmap.  Don't use `np.memmap` for a `np.save` file.

Comment: Both `np.load` and `np.memmap` suggest using `np.lib.format.open_memmap`